# Error compiling the Linux kernel 3.19.0-25-generic

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I try to execute `fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-genericand` compile when building kernel but get the error.

Here error in below

```
arch/x86/built-in.o:(.rodata+0x1cb8): undefined reference to 'sys_monlak'
make[2]: *** [vmlinux] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/su/linux-lts-vivid-3.19.0/debian/build/build-generic'
make[1]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/su/linux-lts-vivid-3.19.0'
make: *** [/home/su/linux-lts-vivid-3.19.0/debian/stamps/stamp-build-generic] Error 2
```

I tried to build kernel following [Build your own kernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) and [Clarkson.edu](http://web2.clarkson.edu/class/cs444/cs444.sp2015/labs/lab04.pdf)

Comment: The Linux kernel is not written in C++! Don't spam tags.

Comment: I would recommend to search SO for other answer where people trying to implement their own system call.

Comment: This link might help http://linuxseekernel.blogspot.ie/2014/07/adding-system-call-in-x86-qemu.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reference to the symbol "sys_monlak" inside any branch of the official Linux kernel. Are you using a branch obtained from somewhere else?

This error would happen if a driver depends on a symbol "sys_monlak" which should be defined elsewhere in the kernel but isn't, or perhaps the correct kernel module isn't enabled in the kernel config.

You can try running:

```
$ grep -R "sys_monlak"
```

If this produces a c file then you can then try to find the Makefile which should compile in this c file. If, for example, the file was called "arch/x86/monlak.c" you might find the following in the file "arch/x86/Makefile":

```
obj-$(CONFIG_MONLAK) += monlak.o
```

In this case you would want to try to enable CONFIG_MONLAK in the kernel config.

The other possibility is that you might want to disable the module that depends on the symbol 'sys_monlak'. Try to carefully read the description in the Kconfig file to see what each module does (the one that depends and the one that provides).